How to use openapi "parameters" section described in separate files?
I use openapi v3.0.3
I have 3 parameters
- name: query
  in: query
  description: ''
  required: false
  schema:
    type: string
- name: limit
  in: query
  description: ''
  required: false
  schema:
    type: integer
- name: offset
  in: query
  description: ''
  required: false
  schema:
    type: integer

In some cases I want to use only query, in the others - want to use all of them: query, limit and offset. I want to have 3 different files: 'query.yaml', 'pagination.yaml' and query_with_pagination.yaml to have ability to include it where I need. For example:
parameters:
  - $ref: '../../shared/parameters/query.yaml'

or
parameters:
  - $ref: '../../shared/parameters/query_with_pagination.yaml'

How do I do that?
(paramters: - allOf: .... doesn't work, because "should have property in")

In OpenAPI 3.x we can only reference individual parameters, not group of parameters - regardless of whether the parameter definitions are stored in the same file or separate files. (This might change in v4 "Moonwalk".)

Assuming you keep the parameter definitions in two files:
query.yaml:
name: query
in: query
description: ''
required: false
schema:
  type: string

pagination.yaml:
limit:
  name: limit
  in: query
  description: ''
  required: false
  schema:
    type: integer

offset:
  name: offset
  in: query
  description: ''
  required: false
  schema:
    type: integer

you can reference the query parameter alone as:
parameters:
  - $ref: '../../shared/parameters/query.yaml'

and reference both query and pagination parameters as:
parameters:
  - $ref: '../../shared/parameters/query.yaml'
  - $ref: '../../shared/parameters/pagination.yaml#/limit'
  - $ref: '../../shared/parameters/pagination.yaml#/offset'


It's sad. I wanted to avoid duplicating code in 200 files. As the result, I need to replace one duplicating code by another :(( This doesn't suit me.
